# Can "take a shot at [someone]" be used as "try to court [someone]"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I know that the expression "have a shot with [someone]" means "to have a chance in successfully wooing [someone]".

And I know that "take a shot at" might mean to have a try, but also literally shooting someone.

Would you recommend against using "take a shot at [someone]" as "try to court [someone]"?

Comment: I think you can use it, but you have to be careful how you word the sentence. : ***take a shot at*** - 
*to make an attempt to do something / give something a shot* - I wasn't sure of the answer, but I thought I'd take a shot at it anyway.  ihttp://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+shot+at - http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+shot+at

Comment: If you take a shot at her you are probably killing her, but if you take a shot at courting her you are taking a chance to win her love.

Comment: Is there a a shorter version for "taking a shot at courting [someone]"?

Comment: I thought that was Cupid's role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "take a shot at" something is (when used figuratively) to make an attempt at the associated action, though often implying that the attempt is made without much preparation.  The term is usually not pejorative with regard to the object of the attempt, though it can (depending on context) imply that the "shooter" is being less that diligent.  Very often the object is regarded as a "long shot", and therefore the attempt is not expected to be successful.

The term could be used to refer to somehow flirting with a potential romantic interest, but there is a danger that the term could be taken to mean being sexually aggressive if crudely applied, since some slang interpretations of "shoot" imply actual sexual activity, perhaps forced.

Eg, one guy might say to his buddy in casual conversation at a party, "You know, Susan over there is kind of interesting -- I think I'll take a shot at her."  But used in anything more formal, or in a large group, such terminology would be considered crass and perhaps offensive.

Comment: I was actually looking for a crass expression, as I'm was actually translating a joke when I had this doubt. Your answer is very clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it could work in the right context - but it also sounds rather crass.

For example, if you said, "I like Suzie, so I figured I'd take a shot at her," I think I would understand what you meant - but it also sounds like you are just casually "gambling" on who might be interested in you, rather than expressing sincere emotion.